# Unable to load BODYSTRUCTURE exception with an email containing an .eml file sent using Thunderbird

Tags: gmail, imap, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap, eml

We have an application that accesses an Gmail account (IMAP) using Java Mail API. Works fine for all types of emails except for a message that contains an .eml file as attachment and the message is sent using Thunderbird.

Here is the exception stack trace when trying to retrieve that message . Please advise.

```
Caused by: com.google.code.javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to load BODYSTRUCTURE
        at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadBODYSTRUCTURE(IMAPMessage.java:1377)
        at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getContentType(IMAPMessage.java:492)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of JavaMail are you using?

You might be running into one of the Gmail bugs described [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Gmail).

Comment: We are using java-gmail-imap-1.4.4-gm-ext-0.5.jar from https://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/

Comment: You should consider switching to the JavaMail 1.4.7 or 1.5.0 release that includes support for Gmail-specific features.  If you need help sorting out whether this is a Gmail bug, post the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) here, or send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Comment: is the JavaMail 1.5.0 compatible with java-gmail-imap-1.4.4-gm-ext-0.5.jar? How much code change will be required?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't looked at it in detail, but based on the link above it shouldn't require large code changes.  Start [here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 6):

I had success using [this](http://dmitriy-bannikov.blogspot.com.tr/2013/05/javaxmailmessagingexception-unable-to.html) method. In short, if your `Message` is of type `MimeMessage` and if you are having this exception, create a new instance of MimeMessage from the original MimeMessage and work on it instead. For example, I was getting this error when I called `getContent()` method of the Message, so I wrote this method to get content:

```
private Object getEmailContent(Message email) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        try {
            return email.getContent();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // handling the bug
            if (email instanceof MimeMessage && "Unable to load BODYSTRUCTURE".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getMessage())) {
                return new MimeMessage((MimeMessage) email).getContent();
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had also the same exception on message.getContentType() as well if the message was digitally signed. The IMAP server was Exchange 2007. I am using javaMail 1.5.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

GMail is known to [produce malformed `BODYSTRUCTURE` responses](http://mailman2.u.washington.edu/pipermail/imap-protocol/2011-May/001413.html), see e.g. [this message from their representative](http://mailman2.u.washington.edu/pipermail/imap-protocol/2011-May/001417.html). Last time I checked (mid-2012), it remained unfixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Another possibility** is that the file representing the emails are deleted from the mail server manually which result in the index(index file) created by the email server being wrong. This can cause the same error.

I was using Mail Enable and the **solution is to delete the index file**(_index.xml in my case)